# Can eclipse detect a file encoding with a specific text header?

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding

What can I do on a file to have eclipse opening it with an UTF-8 encoding on any computer ?

Context : I will distribute a text file to multiple people. This file contains UTF-8 characters but eclipse does not display them correctly by default since the file properties specify that the encoding is "Default (Inherited from container: Cp1252)".

This file is correctly displayed if I change this property to "Other: UTF-8", however I don't want the people who will receive this file to need to configure this property to have a correct display of UTF-8 characters, nor to change any setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text file starts with a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (the sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) then the Eclipse content type system should recognize the file as being UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, actually it works with a random file that I just created and converted to UTF-8 with Notepad++, but for some reason on the specific file I have the encoding is still inherited on eclipse. I checked on a hex dump tool and the first 3 bytes are correct : 0xEF, 0xBB and 0xBF.

Do you know how eclipse is chosing between an inherited encoding or an encoding determined from content ?

Comment: I think Eclipse has a cache of the encodings. You may have to delete the file from Eclipse completely and then add it again.

Comment: It seems to work, thank you ! I tried on another eclipse installation in another workspace and the file was correctly displayed.

Comment: Just for the record, I'd like to add that if the whole solution is working perfectly for eclipse, in my case the BOM header was interpreted by the program using the file (GNU make) and created an error. It's off-topic but this information may be useful ...